# WPF - selected unfocused color of ListViewItem with a GridView

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, listview, gridview

I'm trying to change the default light gray highlight on a selected `ListViewItem` to be the blue highlight that shows up when the `ListView` is focused.  I've been trying to reconcile different StackOverflow answers and sources online, but I haven't figured out what kind of XAML I need yet.  I have the following:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource checkableListViewItem}"
          SelectionMode="Multiple"
          View="{StaticResource fieldValueGridView}"/>
```

The referenced `View` resource is:

```
<GridView x:Key="fieldValueGridView" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
    <GridViewColumn Header="Field">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text=": "/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FieldValue}"/>
</GridView>
```

And the referenced `ItemContainerStyle` resource is:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}"
       x:Key="checkableListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
</Style>
```

The `ListView`'s `IsEnabled` property does change, if that matters.  I wanted to somehow incorporate `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>`, or something similar, to highlight selected `ListViewItem`s that are in an unfocused `ListView`.

I have the following style, but this does not seem to affect `ListViewItem`s in my `ListView`, and I thought the `GridView` that I'm using might be the reason.  When I tried to override the `Template` property, the `View` property got ignored so my `GridView` wasn't being displayed.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                         Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

How do I highlight in blue the selected items in my `ListView` when that `ListView` is unfocused?

Answer (score 8):

This will work for a ListView that doesn't have a GridView

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                         Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

**Update**
**1.Without re-templating when using GridView**

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFD9F4FF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF9BDDFB" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="checkableListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedFill}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB" />
        </Trigger>
        <!-- Or if you want to choose another color for unfocused
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedFill}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        -->
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**2. Re-templating the ListViewItem when using GridView.**

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemHoverFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF1FBFF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFD5F1FE" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFD9F4FF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF9BDDFB" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedInactiveFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEEEDED" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedHoverFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEAF9FF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC9EDFD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="checkableListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"  
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"  
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Border Name="InnerBorder" CornerRadius="1" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Rectangle Name="UpperHighlight" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="#75FFFFFF" />
                            <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"  
                                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"  
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemHoverFill}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCCF0FF" />
                        <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedFill}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB" />
                        <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#80FFFFFF" />
                        <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Fill" Value="#40FFFFFF" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedInactiveFill}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCFCFCF" />
                    </MultiTrigger>-->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedHoverFill}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```