# ContextMenu deselecting treeview item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

When my contextmenu is popped up by right clicking on an item on the treeview, the selected row gets deselected but I want the selection to persist. How do I do this?

```
 <TreeView Name="ProgramTree" ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramItemCollection}">
      <TreeView.ContextMenu>
           <ContextMenu StaysOpen="True"> 
                <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Check Syntax"/>
           </ContextMenu>
      </TreeView.ContextMenu>
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it doesn't deselect your item. Probably you see your item with gray background. That's the color of the focused treeviewitem when it is inactive. You'll need to use styles to get rid of this. There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217735/wpf-selected-unfocused-color-of-listviewitem-with-a-gridview)