# ListView isSelected

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have an listview in my `xaml` that i populate with items like this:

```
List<DataLayer.Models.Dictionary> dicts = DataLayer.Manager.getDictionaries();

if (dicts != null)
{
    foreach (DataLayer.Models.Dictionary dict in dicts)
    {
         this.itemListView.Items.Add(dict);
    }
}
```

My `DataLayer.Models.Dictionary` object have an `isSelected` property along with a `Name` and a `SubName`.

Name and SubName works fine in the template but how can i go about getting the item to be selected and also updated when user clicks an item?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

My xaml now looks like this, but the item is still not selected

```
    <ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0,60,0,0"
        Padding="0,0,0,0"
        IsSwipeEnabled="False"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        SelectionChanged="itemListView_SelectionChanged_1"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        FontFamily="Global User Interface">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Source=Selected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="6">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubName}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875450/binding-the-isselected-property-of-listboxitem-to-a-property-on-the-object-from) please

Comment: Try to change the binding in the item container style from `Selected` to `isSelected` to match your binding source/data model. Try to make sure your `isSelected` property is properly exposed, and there are no binding errors (look at the output window).

Comment: well, that is exactly what i did. My property in DataLayer.Models.Dictionary is named Selected and is public. There is nothing in the debug window indicating that it cannot find the bindiing.

Comment: please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217735/wpf-selected-unfocused-color-of-listviewitem-with-a-gridview) and try playing with it - define the selected looks. note that they select these static brush resources because as i recall, the listview has an issue with not accepting a border brush or background brush when set like `Background ="{Binding whatever}"` but keeps using the static selected brush it is bound to, so they trick it by setting a different one with that key.. i hope this helps.

Comment: actually, first, you might just try adding `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}` to your `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: i never got this to work and ive been on vecation ever since.

Comment: Do you have something in the SelectionChanged event `itemListView_SelectionChanged_1`?

Comment: @RasmusStyrk Do you need me to add anything else to my answer in order to accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Edit] 
Just noticed this question isn't actually tagged WPF; but I hopefully it still applies.

WPF is inherently MVVM. Directly manipulating controls in code behind is generally not a good idea. So it is advised to create a "view-friendly" model called a ViewModel; [See Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial). Also for bindings to be of any use, in a changing environment, you must inform of changes to properties and or collections, so that controls can be updated.

First and formost you have a collection of dictionaries, So you create this collection such that it can notify of changes; [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms668604.aspx) can do that. As a general rule of thumb any collection used by WPF you should just use an ObservableCollection, and/or derive from it.

so here is compete working example:

Bare in mind I'm using [FODY](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to inject my PropertyChanged raisers; [See done manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
public class Dict : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Dict> Dictionaries { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Dictionaries = new ObservableCollection<Dict>()
        {
            new Dict()
                {
                    Name = "English",
                    SubName = "en",
                    Selected = false,
                },

                new Dict()
                {
                    Name = "English-British",
                    SubName = "en-uk",
                    Selected = true
                },

                new Dict()
                {
                    Name = "French",
                    SubName = "fr",
                    Selected = true
                }
        };

        Dictionaries.CollectionChanged += DictionariesCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void DictionariesCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach(var dict in e.NewItems.Cast<Dict>())
                    dict.PropertyChanged += DictionaryChanged;
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (var dict in e.OldItems.Cast<Dict>())
                    dict.PropertyChanged -= DictionaryChanged;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void DictionaryChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dict dictionary = (Dict)sender;

        //handle a change in Dictionary
    }
}
```

With this you can add or remove objects at any time, although here I am just initializing them in the constructor.

Then you would have this in your window or control. I've included the namespaces to make it more self-contained; but this would be for WPF namespaces.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="viewmodel"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=viewmodel}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Dictionaries}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple">

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="6">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubName}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

If you don't use ObservableCollection for your collection, then start adding elements to it *after* WPF has be loaded-up, it will never notify the binding manager that the ListView should be updated.

The above on start up:

[image: On start, unfocused]

you can easily see that the underlying Dictionaries collection is being changed (i.e.its not just the ListView), by overriding the returned value from selected:

```
public bool Selected { get { return true; } set {/* do nothing*/ }}
```

Which means everything is always selected, even if you try to deselect it in the view. It will always look like this:

[image: Always seleted]

Styling is a different issue, the list looks different if it doesn't have focus. [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217735/wpf-selected-unfocused-color-of-listviewitem-with-a-gridview?lq=1)

Now reacting to selection changes could be done in the code-behind, but that would be mixing logic with view.

[Edit] updated to include ability to detect changes in any Dict (including when selected changes)

[You could look into this to simplify it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490533/notify-observablecollection-when-item-changes)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work for windows store apps (WinRT).  [Bindings are not supported on Setters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11869065/641833).  See also [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f0cb96d7-8728-4c5f-96b6-1148a81a8d37/gridviewitemisselected-not-working?forum=winappswithcsharp).